# What is the formula of Coulomb potential?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, voltage, coulombs-law

According to "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics" by Steven Weinberg, the formula of Coulomb potential is 
$$V(r) = - \frac{Z e^2}{r}.$$

But it this true? I calculated the integral 
$$V = - \int _\infty ^r \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{r} =  \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon _0} \frac{1}{r}.$$

I don't know what $Z$ is but I'm unfamiliar with the formula in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top equation is electric potential energy while the bottom is electric potential. They use that coulomb potential energy term for hydrogen like atoms in quantum mechanics where Z is the number of protons in the nucleus.

Comment: This webpage also gives a good explanation on the difference. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elepe.html

Comment: Thank you very much. So the potential energy $U = qV = (-e) V = - \frac{Ze^2}{r}$. Now I understand the difference.

Comment: From Wikipedia: An electric potential (also called the electric field potential or the electrostatic potential) is the amount of work needed to move a unit positive charge from a reference point to a specific point inside the field without producing any acceleration.

Comment: Also From Wiki: Electric potential energy, or electrostatic potential energy, is a potential energy (measured in joules) that results from conservative Coulomb forces and is associated with the configuration of a particular set of point charges within a defined system.

So one is Joules/coulomb and the other is just Joules (energy)

Comment: Maybe to add here: isnt the first formula using cgs units, while the second one using SI.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using the integral $V = -\int \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{dr}$ to calculate the potential is correct, but the expression - $V(r) = \dfrac{-Ze^2}{r}$ is for the **potential energy** of an electron in Bohr's classical model of an atom. 
$Z$ is just the number of protons in the atom.

You could relate the Coulombic force with the centripetal force for an electron in a hydrogen atom, and get the relation,

$$
E_{kinetic} = \dfrac{1}2 mv^2 = \dfrac{1}2 \dfrac{kZe^2}{r}\tag*{(1)}
$$
And by the Virial Theorem for a spherical system ($n = -1$),
$$
2\langle T \rangle = -1\langle U \rangle\tag*{(2)}
$$
Where $\langle T \rangle$ and $\langle U \rangle$ are the total kinetic and potential energies of the system.

Therefore, substituting $(1)$ in $(2)$ , we have,
$$
U = -\dfrac{kZe^2}{r}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we see $Z$ in this equation, we are relating the potential of electrical forces between electron and protons. Hence, $Z$ is a scalar for the number of particles with $+e$, i.e. protons that interact with the $-e$ electron, rendering $Ze^2.$ This comes up in the Bohr model of the hydrogen atom, for example.